# data flow visualisation with real-time data

Tags: workflow, data-visualization, flowchart, alerts

We are building a flow diagram for business alerting. The diagram gives importance to the data-flow and not the "Source" or "End" systems. 
The flow diagram is dynamic (color and width of connectors change based on alerts) where each of the flow is driven by particular data unique to that flow.

We are currently making use of fusioncharts  "Node charts" to construct it and is a data driven flow where the source/destination (from/to) etc is fetched from data. 
BUT...
the fusion charts have one-to-one relationship only. i.e. is one connection between a node to another.
Our case is multiple connections between the nodes as the data flow is different.

I alternatively checked into various data visualization like http://www.visualcomplexity.com and could find that the transportation network maps (tube maps) are better to represent our data

hence
1. Can you suggest any good flow diagram charts with configurable objects? 
2. Any tools to draw tube maps/transportation networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that [d3.js](http://www.d3js.org) is the best tool to visualize and automate data.